# How to update variables in if else statements

Tags: c#, optimization

I want to know is there anyway for a variable to be updated in an if else state, like for example :

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

if(a < b)
{
  a = a + 10;
}

//2nd if
if(a > b)
{
  MessageBox.Show("yay it worked for some reason ");
}
```

I have similar more complex code but it does'nt seem to work, the `int a` for the 2nd if statement is still a 5 rather than a 15.
Sorry for the question if it's easy, I'm still learning C#.

Comment: This is not true, you code works - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPmqod). Provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem

Comment: The code you posted should work as expected. Your problem probably lies in the "more complex" code you didn't show

Comment: Those code doesnt work? Are you sure?

Comment: use the debugger and also the code you posted does work.. and you will see that `15 is > 10` if you put breakpoints in your code you will see perhaps you need to show the complex code this is where your errors are probably happening..

Answer (score -2):

you have to use `else` instead of a second `if` statement.

```
else{
    MessageBox.Show("yay it worked for some reason ");
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is supposed to demonstrate that `a` isn't updated and asks how to update `a`. If you suppose the premise is correct (it doesn't seem it is, however), then changing the condition doesn't help to solve the stated problem.